# Postgres NOT in array

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I'm using Postgres' native array type, and trying to find the records where the ID is not in the array recipient IDs.

I can find where they are IN:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages WHERE (3 = ANY (recipient_ids))
```

But this doesn't work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages WHERE (3 != ANY (recipient_ids))
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages WHERE (3  = NOT ANY (recipient_ids))
```

What's the right way to test for this condition?

Comment: does `WHERE 3 NOT IN recipient_ids` work?

Comment: Related note: as for `text[]` and `int[]` array: `select not(array[1,2,3] @> array[3]);`

Comment: Pro tip: If you are checking if a `null` column is contained or not contained in an array, it will **always** say no. It took me like 20 minutes of debugging several containing methods to come to the conclusion that you cannot check if null is contained in an array

Comment: @AndrePena Regular tip, for whoever stumbles upon these comments: [you *can* check for `null` containment in arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77479697/5298879).

Answer (score 219, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "messages" WHERE NOT (3 = ANY (recipient_ids))
```

You can always negate `WHERE (condition)` with `WHERE NOT (condition)`

Comment: @aschyiel -- You might want to switch back to `ANY` instead of `IN` as your `recipient_ids` input list grows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009706/postgresql-max-number-of-parameters-in-in-clause

Answer (score 61):

You could turn it around a bit and say "3 is not equal to all the IDs":

```
where 3 != all (recipient_ids)
```

From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN17438):

> **9.21.4. ALL (array)**
>
> ```
> expression operator ALL (array expression)
> ```
>
> The right-hand side is a parenthesized expression, which must yield an array value. The left-hand expression is evaluated and compared to each element of the array using the given ***operator***, which must yield a Boolean result. The result of `ALL` is "true" if all comparisons yield true (including the case where the array has zero elements). The result is "false" if any false result is found.

Comment: this doesn't really explain why `any` doesn't work in this case

Comment: This should be accepted as it explained the reason properly. PS you can also find `any` and `all` on postgres doc, which says: "`x <> ANY (a,b,c)`  is equivalent to `x <> a OR <> b OR x <> c`". ref:  http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-any/     http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-all/

Comment: Adding this because of @seanlinsley's comment. `any([array])` returns `true` even if only one evaluation is `true`. So if you have `where 3 != any([1,3])` (desired output is `false`) you will get `true` because this expression evaluates as `3!=1 == true` and `3!=3 == false`. Now you have `any(true,false)`; this returns `true` (which is not what you wanted). In comparison, `3 != all([1,3])` evaluates as `3!=1 == true` and `3!=3 == false` now you have `all(true,false)` which evaluates to `false` (which is what you wanted all along).

Answer (score 44):

### Beware of NULLs

Both `ALL`:

```
(some_value != ALL(some_array))
```

And `ANY`:

```
NOT (some_value = ANY(some_array))
```

Would work as long as `some_array` is not null.  If the array might be null, then you must account for it with coalesce(), e.g.

```
(some_value != ALL(coalesce(some_array, array[]::int[])))
```

Or

```
NOT (some_value = ANY(coalesce(some_array, array[]::int[])))
```

From the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16):

> If the array expression yields a null array, the result of ANY will be null
>
> If the array expression yields a null array, the result of ALL will be null

Answer (score 42):

#### Augmenting the `ALL/ANY` Answers

I prefer all solutions that use `all` or `any` to achieve the result, appreciating the additional notes (e.g. about **NULL**s). As another augementation, here is a way to think about those operators.

You can think about them as *short-circuit operators*:

- `all(array)` goes through all the values in the array, comparing each to the reference value using the provided operator. As soon as a comparison yields `false`, the process ends with false, otherwise true. (Comparable to short-circuit logical `and`.)
- `any(array)` goes through all the values in the array, comparing each to the reference value using the provided operator. As soon as a comparison yields `true`, the process ends with true, otherwise false. (Comparable to short-circuit logical `or`.)

This is why `3 <> any('{1,2,3}')` does not yield the desired result: The process compares 3 with 1 for inequality, which is true, and immediately returns true. A single value in the array different from 3 is enough to make the entire condition true. The 3 in the last array position is prob. never used.

`3 <> all('{1,2,3}')` on the other hand makes sure *all* values are not equal 3. It will run through all comparisons that yield true up to an element that yields false (the last in this case), to return false as the overall result. This is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 20):

an update:

as of postgres 9.3,

you can use `NOT` in tandem with the `@>` [(contains operator)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-range.html) to achieve this as well.

IE.

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "messages" WHERE NOT recipient_ids @> ARRAY[3];`

Answer (score 14):

`not (3 = any(recipient_ids))`?

Comment: Thanks, I was using `3 <> ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3,4])`. It should have worked in that way :\

Answer (score 3):

Note that the ANY/ALL operators will not work with array indexes. If indexes are in mind:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "messages" WHERE 3 && recipient_ids
```

and the negative:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "messages" WHERE NOT (3 && recipient_ids)
```

An index can then be created like:

```sql
CREATE INDEX recipient_ids_idx on tableName USING GIN(recipient_ids)
```

Comment: Unlike other answers, this answer actually makes use of the PostgreSQL array overlap operator. `&&`

Comment: This won't work as written. Array operators like && and @> require both elements to be arrays, which 3 isn't. In order for this to work, the query would need to be written as: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "messages" WHERE ARRAY[3] && recipient_ids`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query
select id from Example where NOT (id = ANY ('{1, 2}'))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since 9.5 [`array_position() is not null`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#id-1.5.8.25.6.2.2.8.1.1.1) can also safely check for `null` containment.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages WHERE (array_position(recipient_ids, your_val) IS null)
```

> `array_position ( anycompatiblearray, anycompatible [, integer ] ) → integer`
>
> Returns the subscript of the first occurrence of the second argument in the array, or `NULL` if it's not present. If the third argument is given, the search begins at that subscript. The array must be one-dimensional. Comparisons are done using [`IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#id-1.5.8.8.14.1) semantics, so it is possible to search for `NULL`.

There's no operator in [GIN index `array_ops`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-builtin-opclasses.html#GIN-BUILTIN-OPCLASSES-TABLE) that uses this function, so the price for using it in a query is that it won't benefit from the index. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/4IKoZDUM)

```
select array_position(array[null],null) is not null;
```

| ?column? |
| --- |
| TRUE |

[`<@`,`&&` and `@>` array operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) as well as [`IN()`, `SOME()` and `ANY()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html) use regular `=` that yields `null` if there's `null` on either side of the operator, which is why none of the examples below works, even though all might seem like they could/should:

```
select null=any(array[null,''])               as "any",
       null=some(array[null,''])              as "some",
       null=all(array[null,null])             as "all",
       null in (null,'')                      as "in",
       null in (select unnest(array[null,'']))as "in(2)",
       array[null] <@ array[null,'']          as "<@",
       array[null] && array[null,'']          as "&&";
```

| any | some | all | in | in(2) | <@ | && |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | FALSE | FALSE |