# Why does Postgres return nothing when testing a column against an empty array?

Tags: postgresql

Tried looking around online, couldn't find much on this.

Suppose the following:

```
create schema if not exists sb;

create table if not exists sb.test (id serial primary key);

insert into sb.test values (1), (2), (3);
```

```
select * from sb.test where id != any('{}'::int[])
```

Why is the resulting set empty?

If I do this, then it works as expected:

```
select * from sb.test where id != any('{}'::int[])

-- [ { "id": 2 }, { "id": 3 } ]
```

How can I get the first query to return all records?

Comment: Such a condition does not make sense to me. The values `1`, `2`, `3` you inserted in your table would all be returned by `select [...] where id != any('{1, 2, 3}'::int[])` since `1` is different from at least one element in `[1,2,3]`, same for `2` and same for `3`; of course, they all are equal to at least one element in `[1,2,3]` too.

Comment: Such a comparison tends to return no records (empty array), all the records (several values in the array) and very occasionally 1 record (array with 1 element); that is a very convoluted way to achieve this behavior. I doubt that is what you want in the first place; What is it exactly that you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to perform a search and, in the event that the result of that search yields a set of users with a length less than that of a specific size, then perform an "extended" search. The endpoint (and therefore query) is the same, which means that the first non-extended search would not be excluding any users. If the first search returns, say, 1 user due to other constraints (such as a specified radius, for example), then the extended search (with an increased radius) should fetch all other users EXCEPT the one already returned from the first search

Comment: As a sidenote, I've noticed that `all` instead of `any` yields the expected result (`select * from sb.test where id != all('{}'::int[])`). Is this the answer to my question, perhaps?

Comment: I'm trying to _exclude_ the ids in that array, not return them (because the ids in that array are that of users that have already been fetched and rendered on the frontend)

Comment: The frontend tells the backend "here are the users and their ids that I already have. Give me more other users"

Comment: Oh yes, my bad, `select * from sb.test where id != all('{}'::int[])` does work.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730777/postgres-not-in-array for an explanation of the `all` vs `any` used with an inequality

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, what you want to do is get all the records from the table except from a list of ids you have already built elsewhere (e.g. in an application connected to your database.
I will demonstrate the possibilities you have with a non-empty array in parameter:

You can do it with an `UNNEST`:

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[1, 2]))
```

Or with a sub-query (below, using `VALUES`):

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE id NOT IN (VALUES(1),(2))
```

Edit:

Like I said in comments, the below works too:

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE id != all(ARRAY[1,2])
```

Id `3` indeed is different from all the values in the array.