# Django-queryset join without foreignkey

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

model.py

```
class Tdzien(models.Model):
  dziens = models.SmallIntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='DZIENS')
  dzienrok = models.SmallIntegerField(unique=True, db_column='ROK')


class Tnogahist(models.Model):
  id_noga = models.ForeignKey(Tenerg, primary_key=True, db_column='ID_ENERG')
  dziens = models.SmallIntegerField(db_column='DZIENS')
```

What I want is to get id_noga where dzienrok=1234. I know that dziens should be

```
dziens = models.ForeignKey(Tdzien)
```

but it isn't and I can't change that. Normally I would use something like

```
Tnogahist.objects.filter(dziens__dzienrok=1234)
```

but I don't know how to join and filter those tables without foreignkey.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's possible to join two tables by performing a raw sql query. But for this case it's quite nasty, so I recommend you to rewrite your models.py.

You can check how to do this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)

It would be something like this:

```
from django.db import connection

def my_custom_sql(self):
    cursor = connection.cursor()    
    cursor.execute("select id_noga
                    from myapp_Tnogahist a
                    inner join myapp_Tdzien b on a.dziens=b.dziens
                    where b.dzienrok = 1234")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    return row
```

Answer (score 24):

No joins without a foreign key as far as I know, but you could use two queries:

`Tnogahist.objects.filter(dziens__in=Tdzien.objects.filter(dzienrok=1234))`

Comment: this will do one query with a subquery.

Comment: This is translated to an `IN` clause, which usually has a size limit. (~1000 items in most databases I'm familiar with)

Comment: @DanielDubovski that is not true https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009706/postgresql-max-number-of-parameters-in-in-clause

Comment: @jperelli you proved that postgres doesn't have a limit, that's just one case..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722220/sql-in-clause-1000-item-limit
All I said is that this is something that people need to be aware of..

Comment: @DanielDubovski The above should not create an item based `IN` clause, but a sub-select, i.e. the id list from `Tdzien.objects.filter(dzienrok=1234)` does not get materialized first. It generates SQL as the answer in your linked post suggest, which does not fall under the `IN` item limit

Answer (score 9):

To provide a little more context around @paul-tomblin's answer,

It's worth mentioning that **for the vast majority of django users; the best course of action is to implement a conventional foreign key**. Django strongly recommends avoiding the use of `extra()` saying "use this method as a last resort". However, `extra()` is still preferable to raw queries using [Manager.raw()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries) or executing custom SQL directly using [django.db.connection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)

Here's an example of how you would achieve this using django's [.extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) method:

```py
Tnogahist.objects.extra(
    tables = ['myapp_tdzien'],
    where = [
        'myapp_tnogahist.dziens=myapp_tdzien.dziens',
        'myapp_tdzien.dzienrok=%s',
        ],
    params = [1234],
    )
```

The primary appeal for using `extra()` over other approaches is that it plays nicely with the rest of django's queryset stack, like filter, exclude, defer, values, and slicing. So you can probably plug it in alongside traditional django query logic. For example: `Tnogahist.objects.filter(...).extra(...).values('id_noga')[:10]`

Answer (score 7):

Could you do this with `.extra`? From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra:

> where / tables
>
> You can define explicit SQL WHERE clauses — perhaps to perform
>   non-explicit joins — by using where. You can manually add tables to
>   the SQL FROM clause by using tables.

Answer (score 1):

You could use following if you select some fields of two models without foreign key.

```python
#import
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL

#result
dziens_result = Tdzien.objects.filter(dzienrok=1234).annotate(
                tno_dziens=Subquery(Tnogahist.objects.filter(dziens=OuterRef('dziens')).values('dziens')
                        )
                ).values_list('dziens', 'tno_dziens', 'dzienrok','id_noga')
```