# inner join between tables no related django

Tags: python, django, django-models, inner-join

I have two models that are not related, but I need to do inner join on date, example:

```
select * from _Money m inner join _Pay p on m.date = p.date


class _Money(models.Model):
    money = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)


class _Pay(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    value = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

how is the way correct to do it on django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`raw` query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/):

```
roles = _Money.objects.raw("""SELECT 
                                  * 
                              FROM
                                  _Money m 
                                  INNER JOIN _Pay p 
                                  ON m.date = p.date""")
```

Also see this similar topic:

- [Django-queryset join without foreignkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590483/django-queryset-join-without-foreignkey)

Comment: I read that using query (sql) is not optimal in django, is it?

Comment: @Mattisbmx django object model doesn't cover every case out there. As docs say: `When the model query APIs don’t go far enough, you can fall back to writing raw SQL.`

Comment: @Mattisbmx and yes, you can also do this in two `filter()` calls, one for `_Money` and another one for `_Pay` but this would be 2 queries, not efficient.