# How can i change this query to ORM?

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

Hi i have two models like this,

```py
class Sample(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)  ##
    processid = models.IntegerField(default=0)  # 


class Process(models.Model):
    sample = models.ForeignKey(Sample, blank=False, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="process_set")
    end_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and I want to join Sample and Process model. Because Sample is related to process and I want to get process information with sample .

```sql
SELECT sample.id, sample.name, process.endstat
FROM sample
INNER JOIN process 
ON sample.processid = process.id 
AND process.endstat = 1;
```

(i'm using SQLite)

I used

```py
sample_list = sample_list.filter(process_set__endstat=1))
```

but it returned

```sql
SELECT sample.id, sample.name
FROM sample
INNER JOIN process 
ON (sample.id = process.sample_id) 
AND process.endstat = 1)
```

This is **NOT** what I want.

How can i solve the problem?

Comment: what does endstat mean?

Comment: it is the field of process's state.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
Process.objects.filter(end_at=1).values('sample__id','sample__name','end_at') 

.values() method returns selective table fields.
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I need sample's queryset.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `sample_list = Sample.objects`.

When you are filtering a model, only the fields defined in the model are selected. In your example, `id and processid`. If you want to retrieve values from related models as a single record you need to use `values or values_list`. To get the desired query you have to do this

```
sample_list = sample_list.filter(process_set__endstat=1).values('id', 'name', 'process__endstat')
```

Btw, Django does `JOIN` on the foreign key field. So, you can't get `ON sample.processid = process.id` since processid is not a ForeignKey field.

Reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values

Comment: Thanks for answering! I found ```JOIN``` not on foreign key field in django. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590483/django-queryset-join-without-foreignkey

Answer (score 0):

I found **JOIN not on foreign key field** in django.

```py
sample_list = sample_list.filter(processid__in=Process.objects.filter(endstat=1)
```

I used the medthod of
[Django-queryset join without foreignkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590483/django-queryset-join-without-foreignkey)

Comment: This is sql subquery, not join. It will translate to a query like `SELECT sample.id, sample.name
FROM sample
WHERE sample.processid IN (SELECT process.id FROM process WHERE endstat=1)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'll think more about that point, though subquery works right now.