# what's the max number of parameters you can pass into IN list of check constraint ? for PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

how many values could be added in "IN" list of check constraint?

```
alter table Customer_Part_1
add check(cust_Key in ('cust1', 'cust2', 'cust3', 'cust4', 'cust5' ................. ?? ))
```

Comment: A second table with a foreign key constraint is a **much** better solution

Comment: I believe it's unlimited - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009706/postgresql-max-number-of-parameters-in-in-clause, although it could be a different limit within a check constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I believe no limit,

look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009706/postgresql-max-number-of-parameters-in-in-clause)
But I would recommen to use join instead... especially on long lists