# how to pass comma seperated UUID in parameterized select query where IN clause

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, spring-jdbc

I have a table with `UUID` as keys and want to fetch multiple rows using select query, so the query is as follow:

```
select * from table1 where ids in (:commaseperatedUUIDs); //DB is postgreSql
```

I am trying it in Java code, I have `List<UUID>` which contains all the UUID but if I make it comma separated of course by using String operations and pass the String in query as parameter then it throws SQL Exception stating

```
operator does not exist: uuid = character varying
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your query evaluates to:

```sql
select * from table1 where ids in ('abc,bcd,dbc')
```

Instead of the desired form:

```sql
select * from table1 where ids in ('abc','bcd','dbc')
```

You can either build the query manually adding multiple parameters and setting each of them individually:

```java
String sql = "select * from table1 where ids in (";
for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) 
    if (i == 0)
        sql += "?"
    else 
        sql += ",?";

sql += ")";
    
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++)
    ps.setString(i+1, ids[i]);
```

Or use the [PreparedStatement::setArray](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setArray(int,java.sql.Array)) method:

```java
String sql = "select * from table1 where ids in (?);";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

ps.setArray(1, connection.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", ids.toArray()));
```

Comment: this is brute force

Comment: It's also more error prone and less clear what the SQL query actually is about. It's best to use the [`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) which supports the such a query clearly e.g. `... IN (:uuids)`. Note this is not the same as using the regular `JdbcTemplate` which will NOT support such a query in this usage manner

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using Spring, I suggest using **NamedParameterJdbcTemplate**, since it automatically formats your list parameters to a db-readable format.

```java
String sql ="select * from table1 where ids in (:commaseperatedUUIDs)"

NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(myJdbcTemplate);
        
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("commaseparateduuids",commaseparateduuids);

namedTemplate.query(sql, parameters);
```

Also, be advised that some RDBMS (e.g. Oracle) impose limits on `IN` clause parameters. This is not the case for Postgresql, but in case you face some database migration in the future, take it into account.

Comment: Postgresql spec-wise doesn't specify a limit, but there is technical limit e.g. as of 9.1 it's 32767 i.e. 2 bytes. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42251312/885922)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring then you can take advantage of the named parameter support and pass in the values for `:commaseperatedUUIDs` as a `java.util.List`. See the docs http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-in-clause

Comment: The documentation states that `Pass in the values as a java.util.List of primitive objects` but I have uuid strings list. And need to specify the type while setting the parameter type.

Comment: What does your table definition look like, or what's the database type of the uuid column?