# long IN-clause causes to break query plan

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-in

I need to update certain rows at once in my database, therefore i have a **IN** clause with ~1200 entries.

When i put only one entry the query-plan is perfectly ok, but with that much entries it breaks and the query never ends.

I already forced the first query plan with **WITH** (CTE) and "SET LOCAL" commands which shows the first plan is still pretty fast with many entries.

Is there any setting in postgres whch controlls how many entries are ok until it switches?

Comment: Can you show your table structure, indexes, query and results of EXPLAIN?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL - max number of parameters in "IN" clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009706/postgresql-max-number-of-parameters-in-in-clause)

Comment: Short answer: don't do this. Instead, put the values into a (temp) table, and/or obtain  them from a subselect or CTE.

Comment: @wildplasser i already tried to pack the IN into the CTE, which still created the bad query plan, i think i'll run it as prepared statement and execute it id by id

Comment: Problem may by somewhere else. Post query and tables structure.

Comment: As others have said: [edit] your question and add the `create table` the `update`  statement and the output of `explain (analyze, verbose)`. Use _formatted_ text please, [no screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) You can also upload the execution plan to http://explain.depesz.com

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91247/optimizing-a-postgres-query-with-a-large-in