# Ecto multiple streams in 1 transaction

Tags: stream, elixir, ecto

### Background

PS: the following situation describes an hypothetical scenario, where I own a company that sells things to customers.

I have an Ecto query that is so big, that my machine cannot handle it. With billions of results returned, there is probably not enough RAM in the world that can handle it.

The solution here (or so my research indicates) is to use streams. Streams were made for potentially infinite sets of results, which would fit my use case.

https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:stream/2

### Problem

So lets imagine that I want to delete All users that bought a given item. Maybe that item was not really legal in their country, and now me, the poor guy in IT, has to fix things so the world doesn't come down crashing.

**Naive way**:

```
item_id = "123asdasd123"

purchase_ids =
      Purchases
      |> where([p], p.item_id == ^item_id)
      |> select([p], p.id)
      |> Repo.all()

Users
    |> where([u], u.purchase_id in ^purchase_ids)
    |> Repo.delete_all()
```

This is the naive way. I call it naive, because of 2 issues:

- We have so many purchases, that the machine's memory will overflow (looking at `purchase_ids` query)
- `purchase_ids` will likely have more than 100K ids, so the second query (where we delete things) will fail as it hits Postgres parameters limit of 32K: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42251312/1337392

What can I say, our product is highly addictive and very well priced!
Our customers simply cant get enough of it. Don't know why. Nope. No reason comes to mind. None at all.

With these problems in mind, I cannot help my customers and grow my [s]empire[/s], I mean, little home owned business.

I did find this possible solution:

**Stream way**:

```
item_id = "123asdasd123"

purchase_ids =
      Purchases
      |> where([p], p.item_id == ^item_id)
      |> select([p], p.id)

stream = Repo.stream(purchase_ids)

Repo.transacion(fn -> 
  ids = Enum.to_list(stream)

  Users
    |> where([u], u.purchase_id in ^ids)
    |> Repo.delete_all()
end)
```

### Questions

However, I am not convinced this will work:

- I am using `Enum.to_list` and saving everything into a variable, placing everything into memory again. So I am not gaining any advantage by using `Repo.stream`.
- I still have too many `ids` for my `Repo.delete_all` to work without blowing up

I guess the one advantage here is that this now a transaction, so either everything goes or nothing goes.

So, the following questions arise:

- How do I properly make use of `streams` in this scenario?
- Can I delete items by streaming parameters (`ids`) or do I have to manually batch them?
- Can I stream ids to `Repo.delete_all` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One cannot directly feed `Repo.delete_all/1` with a stream, but [`Stream.chunk_every/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html#chunk_every/2) is your friend here. One can do somewhat like below (`500` is the default value for `:max_rows` hence we’d use it in `chunk_every/2` as well.)

```elixir
Repo.transacion(fn ->
  max_rows = 500

  purchase_ids
  |> Repo.stream(max_rows: max_rows)
  |> Stream.chunk_every(max_rows)
  |> Stream.each(fn ids ->
     Users
     |> where([u], u.purchase_id in ^ids)
     |> Repo.delete_all()
  end)
  |> Stream.run()
end, timeout: :infinity)
```

Comment: Woow, really cool solution!
One question though, if 1 deletion fails (inside `Stream.each`), will the transaction mechanism be able to revert the other deletions? Or will the DB be left in a somewhat bad state?

Comment: Eh. Everything that happens inside a transaction stays inside a transaction :) Of course, the result would be all-or-none and the failed operation will result in the untouched DB. Please note, that this solution owns a connection until done, so make sure you are not running out of connections (e. g. by running 100 tasks like this in parallel.)

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR of your problem: You'd like to iterate over a large amount of rows and delete them in separate bulks, without preloading all of them to the memory (at once).

To do so:

- you must not load all records at once at the Elixir process level (otherwise it will exceed memory limit and crash),
- you must not load nor delete all records at once at the database level (otherwise it will exceed memory limit and crash).

To achieve this, you should avoid using `Repo.stream` altogether, as unfortunately it forces you to do the whole streaming operation in a single database transaction. [This can cause your database to crash.](https://appunite.com/blog/using-cursor-based-pagination-to-fetch-large-amounts-of-data-using-ecto-in-elixir)

As a workaround I recommend streaming the rows without the need of encapsulating that with a transaction, e.g. using cursor-based pagination.

You could use [`ecto_cursor_based_stream`](https://github.com/allegro/ecto-cursor-based-stream) library to achieve it. Then the code would look like this:

```
max_rows = 500

Purchases
|> where([p], p.item_id == ^item_id)
|> Repo.cursor_based_stream(max_rows: max_rows)
|> Stream.map(& &1.id)
|> Stream.chunk_every(max_rows)
|> Stream.each(fn ids ->
   Users
   |> where([u], u.purchase_id in ^ids)
   |> Repo.delete_all()
end)
|> Stream.run()
```

**Note: Because deleting the rows are no longer part of a single database transaction, if the operation fails while the stream is being run, some rows will get deleted, and some rows will still stay left untouched.** Depending on your requirements, it can be desired or undesired behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't an answer to your question about using streams, but in this scenario, streams might not be necessary depending on the amount of data you are trying to delete. You should be able to delete all of these matching users with a subquery in one query without passing any variables into memory aside from the item_id:

```elixir
sq =
  Purchases
  |> where(item_id: ^item_id)
  |> select([p], p.id)

Users
|> where([u], u.purchase_id in subquery(sq))
|> Repo.delete_all(timeout: :infinity)
```

Comment: I appreciate you popping in, thanks for particiapting! However this solution will blow up because I have over 100K purchases. So when I try to delete them (using the `in subquery` part), it will blow up because psql limit on parameters in only 32K.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix have you tried to do it this way? The only parameter you are passing to the query in my example is `item_id`